# 3 dots at the End of the Excerpt in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

How to get ... (3 dots) at the end of the excerpt?
I am using this function in my functions.php

```
function word_count($string, $limit) {
    $words = explode(' ', $string);
    return implode(' ', array_slice($words, 0, $limit));  
}
```

And echoing like this in my content.php:

```
echo word_count(get_the_excerpt(), '20');
```

I want 3 dots at the end of the excerpt.
Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you done any research? This problem has been solved by many people.

Comment: but where to add?

@Lightness
I did searched and all I got was how to remove 3 dots. I want to add 3 dots.

Comment: You need to read more carefully and search more thoroughly. If you think this hasn't been done before you're off your meds ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your excerpts are always longer than 20 words, you can use the following to append ellipsis any time while truncate it with your `word_count` function

```
echo sprintf("%s&hellip;", word_count(get_the_excerpt(), 20));
```

If the excerpts might also be 20 words or shorter, you should also check for it's length

```
the_excerpt_max_words(20);

function the_excerpt_max_charlength($limit) {

    $words = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt() );

    //if excerpt has more than 20 words, truncate it and append ... 
    if( count($words) > 20 ){
        return sprintf("%s&hellip;", implode(' ', array_slice($words, 0, $limit)) );
    }

    //otherwise just put it back together and return it
    return implode(' ', $words);

}
```

Comment: Note that it'll _always_ append the ellipsis. You may not want that. (I wouldn't.)

Comment: Check if the length of the original text is longer than some cutoff point (say, 21 words) and only if it is, trim the text and append the `&hellip;`. Otherwise just output the original text.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer a simple answer. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt

```
 function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return ''; // replace the normal [.....] with a empty string
 }   
 add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

Comment: In my case this worked when I added a priority in the add_filter 
 add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more', 999);

Answer (score 0):

WordPress's [`the_excerpt()` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt) does this by default (though I think it uses `[...]`).

Comment: That function goes till 55 words.. I want to trim at just 30. Is this possible?

Comment: @TBI sometimes it takes actually reading the page you are being linked to. Like this section https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt#Control_Excerpt_Length_using_Filters

Comment: I read that already before asking. Sadly it doesn't works for me :(
Do I just need to put that function in functions.php and all is over or am I missing something?

Comment: Yep, just put it in functions.php and change the 20 to a 30.

Comment: I tried again. It doesn't works for me. The answer my Mark worked.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is several years old, but since this one comes up when you search for "adding three dots to the end of Wordpress excerpts", I'm still answering it since all the previous answers require changes in the theme's files that might get overwritten once the theme is updated. So here's my answer suggesting to do this with JavaScript.

To do so, install a plugin similar to "Insert Headers and Footers" which allows you to add custom JavaScript at the head, body or footer of your Wordpress blog. Then add this code to the footer:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var x = document.querySelectorAll("div.entry-excerpt");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  for (j = x[i].children.length-1; j >= 0; j--) {
    if (x[i].children[j].tagName == "P") {
      text = x[i].children[j].innerHTML;
      lastchar = text.slice(text.length - 1);
      if (lastchar == ">") break;
      if (lastchar != ".") text += ".";
      text += "..";
      x[i].children[j].innerHTML = text;
      break;
    }
  }
} 
</script>
```

I'm not sure if all themes use the class "entry-excerpt" for excerpts, if yours does not, then change the name of the class in the second line.

What the script then does is to address the last `<p>` element within each excerpt's `<div>` container and adds three dots at the end (there may be more than one `<p>` tag in an excerpt and you don't want three dots after each end of paragraph).
It also avoids printing three dots when there is already a full stop at the end (so only two dots are added), and it does not print three dots at all if the excerpt ends with an HTML tag (which could be an embedded video or something like that where three dots right after don't really look nice). This also gives you the option to control where three dots are placed by just ending your abstract with a HTML tag.